# Restrict to only one item in cart for specific user roles in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, user-roles

I've made a Woocommerce giftshop for a client.
Their customers are other business that let their employees select their gift through the webshop. Each business have 1 login that all employees use.
As of right now, every user is only allowed 1 item in their cart.
If another product is selected, it will overwrite the previous.

Today I was informed that they wish to expand so it will be possible for select users/user roles to have more than 1 product in their cart and "purchase" them.
*Money transactions are not handled directly on the webshop, so purchasing the products sends a list to my client and they take it from there*

The current code I use to impose this limit is the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'custom_only_one_in_cart', 99, 2 );
function custom_only_one_in_cart( $passed, $added_product_id ) {

    // empty cart first: new item will replace previous
    wc_empty_cart();

    // display a message if you like
    wc_add_notice( 'Max number of items in cart reached!', 'notice' );

    return $passed;
}
```

So I'm looking for ideas on how to implement this on specific users or user roles, so the end result will be that most users can only pick one, while a few select user can pick more.

I've already been looking around a lot for a suitable solution, but I haven't been able to find one as of yet.

The solution doesn't have to incorporate the code I provided, either in its current state or in a variation of it, all suitable solutions are welcome.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following code will **restrict add to cart to only one item** based on **defined allowed user roles**:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'user_roles_only_one_in_cart', 50, 3 );
function user_roles_only_one_in_cart( $passed, $product_id, $quantity ) {
    // HERE define the User roles that are allowed to buy multiple items:
    $allowed_user_roles = array('special_customer','administrator', 'shop_manager');

    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    if( array_intersect( $allowed_user_roles, $user->roles ) )
        return $passed;

    // Check if cart is empty
    if( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ){
        // display an error notice
        wc_add_notice( __("Only one item in cart is allowed!", "woocommerce"), "error" );
        // Avoid add to cart
        $passed = false;
    }

    return $passed;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

> For user roles creation and management you can use [User Role Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) plugin (for example).

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much. It worked perfectly! Cheers!